# ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer com.google.android:android:jar:4.1.1.4

Tags: android, eclipse, maven

I am trying to build a new Android project with maven and eclipse, after maven built my workspace i get this error in pom.xml :

> `ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer com.google.android:android:jar:4.1.1.4 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/
>    maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or 
>    updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact com.google.android:android:jar:4.1.1.4 from/to central (http://
>    repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): No response received after 60000`

this error refers to these lines of pom.xml :

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>${platform.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

there is a saying [here](https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/QuickStartForEclipseProject) and i think it is about this problem but following that link gets me no where.

any help will be apreciated.

===>EDIT<===

i managed to solve the problem by editing pom.xml :

```
                <configuration>
                <sdk>
                    <platform>16</platform>
                </sdk>
            </configuration>
```

i changed the platform to 18 then did a `clean install` and that did the trick.
i also edited  AndroidManifest.xml and project.properties and did the same thing.

i hope this help.

Comment: try emptying up your local Maven repository  (i.e. ~/.m2/repository)

Comment: no that did not solve it

Comment: Do you get the same issue when you run your Maven build from the command line?

Comment: i have not tried that, and i dont know how to :-?

Comment: are you running `mvn clean install` from eclipse or via command line?

Comment: @dave regarding how to run mvn clean install from command line: http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi#Installation

Comment: i am trying it from eclipse

Comment: problem is that eclipse is running an embedded Maven and it's probably having some configuration problems. My advice would be to first configure on your machine Maven so it will be external than having it embedded in eclipse (optional, you might want to configure it to be ran through the command line) and you can either configure eclipse to use your external Maven distribution or just run it through the command line directly.

Comment: thanks fellas i edited the post about solution. thank you